# How to tell if dmg file contains universal binaries, i.e. if it has been compiled for arm64 hardware

Tags: install, dmg, apple-silicon, universal-binaries

Can you tell from a `.dmg` file if it contains arm64 binaries?

I've got a Mac mini M1 running Big Sur. I don't want to run apps under Intel, only arm64. I don't even have Rosetta installed, and want to avoid installing it.

I can install apps, try to run them, and see if they request Rosetta installation. But I'd like to know if the `.dmg` file contains binaries compiled for arm64 without running the application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A DMG is just a container, it doesn't know about it contents.

If application is distributed without a package (so it's application you can just drag&drop to `/Applications`) you can run

```
hdiutil attach THE_DMG
file /Volume/THE_DMG/THE_APPLICATION.app/Contents/MacOS/*
```

to see what kind of binary it is.

Comment: Right, I realize that it is a container, but is there no tool to inspect it to figure out if it contains arm64 binaries or not?

Comment: @KlasMellbourn See the second part of the answer :-) You will need to mount the DMG to do so of  course.

Comment: Ok, and I can use `hdiutil attach` to mount it

Comment: @KlasMellbourn I usually just double-click, but hdiutil works as well :-)

Comment: But won't double-clicking initiate installation?

Comment: @KlasMellbourn Not sure DMG can even do that.

Comment: Generally speaking opening a DMG will not initiate an installation. It is possible to set up a DMG to do that but you can simply cancel the installer without running the App itself. And if it is just an App inside the DMG you can get info on it to see what kind of binary it is.

Comment: I am fairly sure it's not actually possible to make a DMG file automatically launch anything. They can display a license agreement, but they can't actually launch an application. As others have said, `.dmg` is just a container for a filesystem and double clicking simply mounts it so you can view (and optionally install) the contents

Answer (score 1):

you can get info on the app, by right click and get info, or cmd+i, and see what it is designed for. Intel, Apple Silicon, or Universal.

Comment: The app file, yes, but not the `.dmg` file.

Comment: @KlasMellbourn a DMG is architecture-independent

Comment: This would be a good answer to a [question asking how to tell an app is architected](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/429197/) as opposed to a question on what a package contains. It’s like asking what food is in the foil tray or the paper bag. Image files lack any code since they contain other files.